# What is DELFI Ecosystem?

Tags: ocean

I have seen references to a Schlumberger product called DELFI. What is it specifically? I have looked for materials describing this and have not been able to determine what it is or what is possible with it.

Comment: VTC as this isn't about programming

Answer (score 3):

Have you made a quick Google search? https://www.software.slb.com/delfi

Very odd, you are part of SIS, should be easy for you to contact the relevant people internally.